# UNIX- How to cut specific characters in the particular sentence

Tags: linux, unix, sed

How to cut specific characters in the particular sentence?

**Input String:**

```
7,717   http-16502-2    INFO    com.****.mxxdctm.cscxscxs**-    new name:/opt/docu/fs1_1/fs_cache/09vvadadaca.mghyyysss.excel12book
7,717   http-16502-2    INFO    com.****.mxxdctm.cscxscxs**-    new name:/opt/docu/fs1_1/fs_cache/09vvadadaca.bcdvsxsas.pdf
7,717   http-16502-2    INFO    com.****.mxxdctm.cscxscxs**-    new name:/opt/docu/fs1_1/fs_cache/09vvadadaca.nmncdvsxsas.pdf
```

I want to cut the string which is before the file extension of the above sample sentence.

Below output I am looking for:

```
bcdvsxsas
mghyyysss
nmncdvsxsas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F. '{print $(NF-1)}' inFile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..I m new to unix.could you please explain the above commands.so i could use for cutting other strings

Comment: @senthilkumar In the solution, we are using `.` as a field separator to split the fields. `NF` is an `awk` built-in variable that holds number of fields. `$NF` holds the value of last field, so by printing `$(NF-1)` we are printing the second last field from every line without hard coding that we need the 5th field from every line. It is something similar to `cut -d\. -f5 inFile.txt`. If your data is consistent then hard coding is perfectly fine. However, if the data is not consistent then backtracking from the end of the line and picking the second last field is a smarter way to solve it.

Comment: Might want to add `NF` before the statement `NF{print $(NF-1)}` as blank lines will cause awk to abort